# How to Org Capture at current location?

Tags: org-capture

I have successfully used org-capture, and have many templates.

Recently I have written a new template, where I want the target to be the location from where I am calling the capture command.

I have tried many things, and the only way I have been able to get it to work is using the *Target location:* `Current clocking task:`. This works just the way I like, except for the fact that I have to start clocking in order to capture.

Is there a way I can still gain the same functionality, without the need for clocking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for this, from the `org-capture` doc:

```
When called with a ‘C-0’ (zero) prefix, insert a template at point.
```

So if you have `org-capture` bound to for example `C-c c`, then you could use `C-0 C-c c` to choose a capture template and insert in the current buffer.

You can always bind this to some other key sequence, if using a prefix isn't convenient. For example:

```
(defun org-capture-at-point ()
  "Insert an org capture template at point."
  (interactive)
  (org-capture 0))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") #'org-capture-at-point)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Somehow I am not able to enter `C-0`. When I do that, it is interpreted as `C-u 0`. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. It works anyway. All I needed to do is change the *Target location:* from `Current clocking task:` to `File` and keep that field empty.

Comment: As you found, `C-0` is really just a more convenient binding for `C-u 0`. You can use `C-u` to enter any numeric prefix argument, but for 0-9 there are direct bindings.